# How can I give a name to an image in Corel with Eps format?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, corel-draw

I want to export my images from Corel into InDesign. So I export it with a name that I want, but the problem is that when I export my image, Corel automatically adds a number sequence (eg. ...-1, ...-2, ...-3, etc.) and also creates two files with the `EPS` format.  One of them does not have anything in it.

How can I export my images with the name that I want? And how can I get rid of another file that Corel creates automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where saving it as an old Illustrator format from CorelDraw will be much better than battling different EPS handling ideas.

Then open in Illustrator and copy/paste the parts you want to Indesign.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you export you select "export selected only" in the export dialogue that pops up - otherwise you'll create a file for every page in your CorelDRAW workspace.